# Why XFS under LUKS encryption is so slow (Samsung 980 PRO SSD)

Tags: luks, xfs

I tried to measure the overhead of LUKS/dm-crypt encryption on a XFS filesystem with default settings. It turned out that on a laptop with Samsung 980 PRO SSD (NVME variety) the overhead of `git status` on a huge tree (cromium checkout) compared with raw partition became slower by 15-20% while `tar xf` that expanded into the corresponding tree became slower by 25-30%. For ext4 the slowdown for `git status` was 8% and 20%, for btrfs it was 10% and 17%. This is under Fedora and 5.14.10 kernel.

[Cloudflare blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-linux-disk-encryption/) mentioned 2 new options that are now available for tuning encryption performance (--perf-no_read_workqueue, --perf-no_write_workqueue for cryptsetup), but in my case they slowed things down. And in any case it will not explain discrepancy between XFS and other filesystems. So what makes XFS particularly vulnerable to LUKS overhead?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the problem was caused by LUKS setup on Fedora to default to use 512 byte sectors. Increasing that to 4K as was suggested on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/rxeyhd/fastest_filesystem_with_encryption_for_development/) and using --perf-no_read_workqueue option to `cryptsetup open  --type=luks` was sufficient to reduce the LUKS encryption overhead for XFS to 7-9%.

The reason for 512 was that Samsung 980 PRO reports that by default and Fedora 35 matches that.